# What is the difference between git-man and git-doc packages?

Tags: apt, git, version-control

Are they the same thing? Is `git-doc` obsolete?

Also how can I find information about packages on apt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences:

- `git-man` contains [files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/git-man/filelist) for `man git`.
- `git-doc` contains [files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/git-doc/filelist) for html-formatted help.

Comment: How do I use git-doc? Do I just run it as a command?

Comment: You can read it with  web-browser - `xdg-open /usr/share/doc/git-doc/index.html` .